# XML Data not showing up in HTML file

Tags: html, xml

I have an xml file titled "xmldata.xml" located in the same folder as my index.html file. I have this code to display my xml data on my html page but it is not working. any ideas?

```
    <script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","xmldata.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("company");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("c_id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("c_name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

Comment: Any javascript console errors?  Does the `GET` request execute without any errors?

Comment: This question would be more useful if you clarified the "it is not working."  What happens?  Do you see any errors?  No output?  Malformed output?  Something else?

Comment: Can we have the XML file?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine on my own machine.

### I used the following xml code for xmldata.xml:

```
<company>
    <c_id> 0 </c_id>
    <c_name>moo</c_name>
</company>
```

### I used the following HTML/javascript code:

```
<html>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","xmldata.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("company");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("c_id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("c_name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
</script>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe it is a permissions issue here on my companies servers. is there an alternative way to display xml on an html file rather than using the above method?

Comment: Is the XML and HTML file on the same server? I would assume so as your using relative path. Is the actual XML file in the correct folder and in the same path? Are you using google chrome? Which browser specifically? Could you take a look at the console for error messages?